# How to use jQuery Tokeninput with best_in_place gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

When I click the best_in_place span class it gives text input form, so how can we use that text input field for jQuery Tokeninput functionality, really getting no idea. What is the id of text input field created by best_in_place.

html file is,

```
<tbody class="song-index">
   <td><%= best_in_place @song, :name %></td>               
</tbody>
```

js file is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();  
});
```

Comment: I have updated the question description, actually I would like to provide a custom id to best_in_place generated text input field, so that i can use it on js file for use tokeninput initialization

Comment: could you please share how you fixed this. I am in a similar situation